# Java time, how decide what date is last

Tags: java, time

I need to use java.time. I have several dates in LocalTime, and I need to decide which is last. Do You know what class can I use? I am green so far(I am learning java, and this is my first issue on Stackoverflow), tried to look in oracle docs but can`t find this.
 I

Comment: util.Date class, use a list and sort it...

Comment: What does "I have several dates" mean? You have some `Date` instances? Some strings? Some dates in mind? Do you have some actual code?

Comment: could you be more specific? what does it mean I am green so far??

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ This person just says he uses an advanced, standard library such as `java.time` and you recommend the old, slow and non-recommended `util.Date`? Why?

Comment: i need to use java.time not java.Date

Comment: Suppose they weren't dates but numbers. Would you know how to do that?

Comment: @dzefrej0 A `LocalTime` has no date. Edit your Question to use correct terms and clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking, you have a collection of `LocalTime` and you wish to get the largest (i.e. latest) in the collection. If that's correct then, in Java 8 you can use the following:

```
Optional<LocalTime> latest = timeCollection.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

It returns an `Optional` to allow for empty collections.

Comment: Using streams, comparator, and Optional is overkill for a beginners question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a poor Question for Stack Overflow, as you should spend some time learning the basics of programming ( collections, looping, comparisons, sorting ). I suggest reading the [Oracle Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

A quick Answer…

Collect your objects.

```
List<LocalTime> times = new ArrayList<>();
times.add( oneLocalTime );
times.add( anotherLocalTime );
```

Sort your collection using a utility method in [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).

```
Collections.sort( times );
```

Access the first element in list for earliest, and last element for latest.

```
LocalTime earliest = times.get( 0 );
LocalTime latest = times.get( times.size() - 1 );
```